# Cube root guessing game

Tags: c++

I am making a simple cube root guessing game, where a random is generated and it's cube is displayed, the user then enters what the cube root is. Here is my program:

```
int main()
try {
    int max, min;
    max = 99; min = 1; // only cubes of 1-99 are displayed

    // display the title
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\tCube Root Game" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t=============\n" << endl;
    srand(time(0)); // seed for random number generator

    // display 10 numbers for the user to guess the cube root
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {      
        int answer; // answer inputted by the user
        int temp = rand() % (max - min) + min; // random number
        int t3 = temp * temp * temp; // cube of the random number

        cout << "\tEnter the cube root for " << t3 << " : ";
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == t3) {
            cout << "\tCorrect answer!\n" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "\tIncorrect answer\n" << endl;
        }
    }
    keep_window_open("q");
}
catch (runtime_error& e) {
    cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    keep_window_open("q");
    return 1;
}
catch(...) {
    cerr << "Unexpected error.\n";
}
```

The problem is that when I correctly enter a cube root, it always says it's incorrect, but the if comparison seems okay to me, so I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (answer == t3)
```

Didn't you mean this:

```
if (answer == temp)
```

(you want the user to guess the root, not the cube, right?) :-)